# 'int' object has no attribute 'den' error message in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-requests

```py
def gcd(m, n):
    while m % n != 0:
        m, n = n, m % n
    return n


class Fraction:
    def __init__(self, top, bottom):
        if not isinstance(top, int):
            raise ValueError("Numenator should be an integer.")
        if not isinstance(bottom, int):
            raise ValueError("Denomenator should be an integer.")
        common = gcd(top, bottom)
        self.num = top // common
        self.den = bottom // common

    def __str__(self):
        return "{:d}/{:d}".format(self.num, self.den)

    def __eq__(self, other_fraction):
        first_num = self.num * other_fraction.den
        second_num = other_fraction.num * self.den
        return first_num == second_num

    
    
    
    def __add__(self, other_fraction):
        new_num = self.num * other_fraction.den \
                  + self.den * other_fraction.num
        new_den = self.den * other_fraction.den
        return Fraction(new_num, new_den)
    #__radd__ is only called if the left object does not have an __add__ method, or that method does not know how to add the two objects.
    def __radd__(self, other_fraction):
        new_num = self.num * other_fraction.den \
                  + self.den * other_fraction.num
        new_den = self.den * other_fraction.den
        return Fraction(new_num, new_den)
   

    def show(self):
        print("{:d}/{:d}".format(self.num, self.den))

    def get_num(self):
        return self.num

    def get_den(self):
        return self.den
    
    def __sub__(self, other_fraction):
        new_num = self.num * other_fraction.den \
                  - self.den * other_fraction.num
        new_den = self.den * other_fraction.den
        return Fraction(new_num, new_den)
    
    def __mul__ (self, other_fraction):
        new_num = self.num * other_fraction.num
        new_den = self.den * other_fraction.den
        return Fraction(new_num, new_den)
    
    def __truediv__(self, other_fraction):
        new_num = self.num * other_fraction.den
        new_den = self.den * other_fraction.num
        return Fraction(new_num, new_den)
    
    def __gt__(self,other_fraction):
        return self.num*other_fraction.den>self.den*other_fraction.num
    
    def __ge__(self,other_fraction):
        return self.num*other_fraction.den>=self.den*other_fraction.num
    
    def __lt__(self,other_fraction):
        return self.num*other_fraction.den<self.den*other_fraction.num
    
    def __le__(self,other_fraction):
        return self.num*other_fraction.den<=self.den*other_fraction.num
    
    def __ne__(self,other_fraction):
        return self.num!=other_fraction.num and self.den!=other_fraction.num
```

So this is what I am doing now and when I run this code with

```
print(x + 1)
print(1 + x)
```

these two, I get 'int' object has no attribute 'den' this error message.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-1ad5c0ae446d> in <module>
      1 #Test 7 radd
      2 
----> 3 print(x + 1)
      4 print(1 + x)

<ipython-input-3-ae7cd5826bd8> in __add__(self, other_fraction)
     27 
     28     def __add__(self, other_fraction):
---> 29         new_num = self.num * other_fraction.den \
     30                   + self.den * other_fraction.num
     31         new_den = self.den * other_fraction.den

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'den' this is my traceback

Comment: Please add attribute error in the question section

Answer (score 0):

By accessing `other_fraction.den`, your `__add__` method assumes the second operand of an add operation to have a `den` attribute, and yet by doing `x + 1` you're passing to it `1`, an `int` object, which does not have a `den` attribute, as the second operand.

You can work around this by making `1` a `Fraction` object first before performing an add operation:

```
x + Fraction(1, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have written all your dunder methods assuming that the other instance would be the same as your class i.e. `Fraction`, whereas you are performing such operation that the other instance is an `int`. You should check if other is an instance of int and perform proper operations:

```
def __add__(self, other_fraction):
    if isinstance(other_fraction, int):
        other_fraction = Fraction(other_fraction, 1)
    new_num = self.num * other_fraction.den + self.den * other_fraction.num
    new_den = self.den * other_fraction.den
    return Fraction(new_num, new_den)
```

Similarly for other dunder methods.